# Oracle Apex Sum of 2 interactive grid columns in third grid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have 3 Interactive grids in my Apex application.
The source table for all the three is same, just that the flags are different.

First grid:

```
    select kpi_a_pk, dept_name, to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_2,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_3,'999,999,999,999') 
FROM KPI where dept_name = 'A'
```

Columns are numeric but need to be rendered comma separated. In processes i am converting them using to_number to save them.

Second grid:

```
select kpi_a_pk, dept_name, to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_2,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_3,'999,999,999,999') 
from KPI where dept_name = 'B'
```

Third grid needs to be sum of the columns A and B:

```
select kpi_a_pk, dept_name, to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_2,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_3,'999,999,999,999') 
from KPI where dept_name = 'C'
```

So its expected query would have the logic like:

```
KPI_A_1 =  case when dept_name = 'A' then kpi_a_1
+case when dept_name = 'B' then kpi_a_1
```

But when i try writing something like this in query, it returns nothing. I need to convert to number for calculation . sum up, then again use to char to separate comma.

```
select kpi_a_pk, dept_name, 
case when dept_name = 'A' then to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999') else null end +
case when dept_name = 'B' then to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999') else null end
,to_char(kpi_a_2,'999,999,999,999'),to_char(kpi_a_3,'999,999,999,999') 
from KPI where dept_name = 'C'
```

So if Grid for DEPT A:

[image]

Grid for DEPT B:

[image]

Then expected Grid for Dept C should be:

[image]

How can i modify the third grid query to get the values added cell by cell?
In my opinion DA shouldn't be needed.
I tried modifying the query but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your logic; why do you `TO_CHAR` those numbers? Wouldn't you rather use **format mask** to display them properly?

As of problem you have in the 3rd grid which doesn't display the sum:

- don't sum strings, as that's what you are doing. `TO_CHAR(kpi_a_1, ...)` is a string. That's as if you want to know result of `av$#5 + #$fs`. Sum numbers, not strings
- though, if Oracle managed to implicitly convert those values into numbers, it did that (and didn't raise an error). But, this is what might be bothering you:

  ```
  case when dept_name = 'A' then to_char(kpi_a_1,'999,999,999,999') else null end
                                                                         ----
  ```

  You're adding `NULL` if dept_name isn't `'A'`. Adding `NULL` to anything results in `null`:

  ```
  SQL> select 1 + null as result from dual;

      RESULT
  ----------


  SQL>
  ```

  Maybe you'd rather use `else 0`

Comment: Format doesn't work here specially if the user wishes to input numbers as comma separatd, thus the use of to_char. Even if i remove to_char and add simple numbers it doesn't eturn anything. What am i doing wrong here?    case when dept_name = 'A' the kpi_a_1 else 0 end + case when dept_name = 'B' then kpi_a_1 else 0 end as RESULT

Comment: Ok, i used with clause to store dept A and B values in subqueries and then used it to calculate C and it worked. Not sure why case did not work.

Comment: Even if i used 0 other than null it did not work.

Comment: Hm, strange (from my point of view). Never mind, I'm glad you made it work.